# Replace column names with extracted strings

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, names

I'm trying to replace some of the columns in my data frame with extracted strings from each column name. This is my current data frame:

```
  Date      Time   Temp  ActivityLevelActivity  ExplainActivityvalues4  AppetiteLevelAppetite
  10/22/21  10:26  76    4                      Activity was low        8
  10/23/21  8:42   79    3                      Activity was low again  7
```

I would like to replace the "ActivityLevelActivity" and "AppetiteLevelAppetite" column names with just "Activity" and "Appetite". I would like to change the "ExplainActivityvalues4" to "Activity_Comments".

I have tried:

```
gsub("Level", "[^L]+", names(df))
gsub("Explain", "(?<=\\n)[[:alpha:]]+(?<=\\v)", names(df))
```

I used "Level" and "Explain" as the patterns because the word "Level" is included in every column name where I would just like to take the first word. "Explain" is included for every column name where I would like to take the middle word and add "_Comments".

Essentially, I would like the new data frame to look like this:

```
Date      Time   Temp  Activity  Activity_Comments       Appetite
10/22/21  10:26  76    4         Activity was low        8
10/23/21  8:42   79    3         Activity was low again  7
```

EDIT:

To explain further, here are all of my column names:

```
names(df) <- c(“Date”, “Time”, “Temp”, “ActivityLevelActivity”, “ExplainActivityvalues4”, “AppetiteLevelAppetite”, “ExplainAppetitevalues4”, “ComfortLevelComfort”, “ExplainComfortvalues4”, “DemeanorLevelDemeanor”, “ExplainDemeanorvalues4”, CooperationLevelCooperation”, “ExplainCooperationvalues4”, “HygieneLevelHygiene”, “ExplainHygienevalues4”, “MobilityLevelMobility”, “ExplainMobilityvalues4”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have three columns and there's not really much of a shared pattern here, it would just be easier to more directly use `rename`.

```
# library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  rename(
    Activity = ActivityLevelActivity,
    Appetite = AppetiteLevelAppetite,
    Activity_Comments = ExplainActivityvalues4)
```

Comment: sorry, I didn’t explain further. I actually have many columns that follow a pattern. Check my edits above!